# Error when attempting to connect to a non-default database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, connection

Here is my database configuration for the database I'm attempting to connect to. It is different for this particular model.

```
$db['campaignsDB']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['campaignsDB']['username'] = 'root';
$db['campaignsDB']['password'] = '';
$db['campaignsDB']['database'] = 'sf_campaigns';
$db['campaignsDB']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['campaignsDB']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['campaignsDB']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['campaignsDB']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['campaignsDB']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['campaignsDB']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['campaignsDB']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['campaignsDB']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['campaignsDB']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['campaignsDB']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['campaignsDB']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I have created a crud_model and I'm sure the functions are written right, but I'm going to include the relevant part...

```
class CRUD_model extends CI_Model
{
    protected $database = null;
    protected $_table = null;
    protected $_primary_key = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database($this->database, TRUE);
    }
```

What I'm having a problem with is as follows:

I create a campaigns_model...

```
class Campaigns_model extends CRUD_model
{
    protected $database = "campaignsDB"; //DEFINE database
    protected $_table = "camp_forminfo";
    protected $_primary_key = "form_id";

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Now I'm returning to object oriented programming after a long hiatus so it could be that I'm missing some important part here, but I could have sworn that by defining a variable of a base class in a derived class it would thus be defined when I try to use the base class' method. I attempt to use the CRUD_model's insert function in my controller...

First I load the campaigns_model...

```
class Campaigns extends MY_Controller
{
    private $layout = "";
    private $content = "";

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct($this->layout);
        $this->load->model('campaigns_model');  
    }
```

Then I use it in my controller function...

```
public function saveForm()
{
    $this->campaigns_model->insert([
        'form_name' => $this->input->post('form_name'),
        'form_leads' => $this->input->post('form_leads'),
        'form_content' => $this->input->post('form_content'),
        'form_template' => $this->input->post('form_template')  
    ]);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
An Error Was Encountered

You have not selected a database type to connect to.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough I was able to make this all work with a slight modification to my CRUD_model code.

By changing this...

```
class CRUD_model extends CI_Model
{
    protected $database = null;
    protected $_table = null;
    protected $_primary_key = null;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database($this->database, TRUE);
}
```

To this...

```
class CRUD_model extends CI_Model
{
    protected $database = null;
    protected $_table = null;
    protected $_primary_key = null;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database("".$this->database."", TRUE);
}
```

It worked... by forcing that variable to be interpreted as a string it worked. Why that is, I've yet to learn, perhaps someone can share?

Comment: It is strange indeed. Can you dump the $this->database and "" . $this->database and see what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but this is how I do it within my double database apps:

```
class CRUD_model extends CI_Model{
    protected $database = null;
    protected $_table = null;
    protected $_primary_key = null;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->db = $this->load->database($this->database, true);
    }
```

Comment: BTW: Try to avoid 'mysql' driver. As far as I'm concern it doesn't work well.  For example, there are some transactional issues with mysql driver (transactions just doesn't work).

Use mysqli instead.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the driver as suggested as I've heard this before too. Unfortunately adding that line into the CRUD_model's constructor did not work, but was worth a try. What I ended up doing as a workaround solution is loading the database in my controller's constructor. Once I did that, it seemed to work; I am however, waiting to see if someone has a different solution.

Comment: Please note that this has not infact helped the issue... I'm now getting an error that says "No database selected".